# Issue with grass that has a lot of crab grass. What do I do?

Tags: lawn, grass, weeds, lawn-repair, crabgrass

I recently filled in some low spots in my lawn with soil and seeded.  The grass I planted has now sprouted a lot of (I think) crab grass.  Do I need to rip up and re-seed? Or, would a simple chemical treatment work?  It is pretty widespread in the areas I had new soil, so pulling it would be laborious but not impossible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would wait until next spring an put down pre-emergent crabgrass herbicide. It will not affect perennial grasses.

Answer (score 0):

Very often the best tool to remove weed from your lawn is not to try to fight the weed, but to help the lawn grass to outperformance the weed.

I can personally confirm moving the lawn frequently and close to the ground effectively reduces the crap grass, because it is then left without any green parts.